# nameof in attribute produces empty string

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, nameof, sourcegenerators

Right now I'm developing INotifyPropertyChanged source generator (to study generators) and stumbled at weird bug(?). When attribute uses `nameof` to reference generated property corresponding `AttributeData.ConstructorArguments` contains empty string instead of property name.

```cs
[AutoNotify]
partial class Sample
{
    string _someProp;
    
    [NotifyDependsOn(nameof(SomeProp), nameof(_someProp))]
    public string Dependent => _str;

    public string Foo() => SomeProp; // added by generator
}
```

`SomeProp` is generated property, which is not added to source at the moment. Everything works if  member is user-defined. This code compiles.

[image]

1. Is it bug in compiler or it's *by design*?
2. What is best way to workaround this? Go down from semantic model to syntax or do something else?

Comment: Assuming this code is in the generator (or in the another one) itself,  the property is not generated yet, so the semantic model should know nothing about it, so you should switch to using syntax trees for this case.

Comment: I'd encourage you to file a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn, as this might be something we can address. It seems a bit odd we actually need the member to exist before we can provide a value for nameof() since well, the name is there regardless. But that might be difficult to fix.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I've created bug report https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52013